# how to "disable" javascript function after being ran once

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have two html buttons that each run a different function (both functions are below).  Basically, you click one of the two buttons to add a Google Maps actionlistener to the map.  I've successfully got that to work.  The only problem is that I only want the actionlistener to be available one click.  After that one click I want the user to have to click another button before the actionlistener "listens" again.  I hope that makes sense.

```
    function addLaunch() {
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map

    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
};
function addFishing() {  
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
    fishinfowindow.open(map, marker);
});
};
```

So I just tried this:

```
function addLaunch(setBoolean) {
var clicked = new Boolean(false);
    clicked.boolValue = setBoolean;
if (clicked = true) {
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map

        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        clicked.boolValue = false;
    });
   }
   else {
   google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, "click");
   }
 };
```

and it didn't work..... Please point me in the right direction...
(BTW, the button passed "true" to the 'setBoolean'.

This works to disable all actionlisteners after the first click.  But it doesn't reset after the button is clicked again.

```
    var temp = true;
function addLaunch() {
    if (temp == true) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map

        });
infowindow.open(map, marker);
        temp = false;
        if (temp == false) {
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, "click");
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: an if statement with a `clicked` flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce()`

From the [**documentation:**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event)

> **addListenerOnce(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:Function)**
>   MapsEventListener Like addListener, but the handler removes itself
>   after handling the first event.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

Example-

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="a()" />
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="b()" />
```

and

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var temp = true;
    function a() {
        if (temp == true) {
            alert('1'); //Replace your function's code here
            temp = false;
        }
    }
    function b() {
        if (temp == false) {
            alert('2'); // Replace your function's code here
            temp = true;
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Cdeez, I think that still lets the user click as many times on the actual map as they want.  It just doesn't let you also add the other button at the same time, right?  I would still need the button to get disabled after a single click.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Will try updating my answer in a while.

Comment: after I changed the button to html, it work! sort of...  The above code disables the map action listeners.  Now I just need to figure out how to reset if the button is clicked again...

Comment: I changed the buttons to html in the code now. _reset if the button is clicked again_ , I dont get it. With the above code you can alternatively execute each listener functions any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 boolean flags `(btn1Clicked, btn2Clicked)`, representing the state of the buttons (clicked or not), so you can procced Listening only if `btn2Clicked` is true.