# buttons and Google InfoWindows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to “disable” javascript function after being ran once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096807/how-to-disable-javascript-function-after-being-ran-once)

I've got two buttons that when clicked, run one of the two functions below:

```
 function addlaunchMark() { 
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
             map: map     
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
        marker.setMap(null);
            });
        });
    };


  function addfishingMark() {       
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map
           });
    fishinfowindow.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(fishinfowindow, "closeclick", function() {
    marker.setMap(null);
        });
    });
};
```

So what happens is when someone clicks one of the buttons, it turns on the action listener under the function.  The problem that if you click the other button, the one you have already clicked stays on.  So when you click again, you get two markers and two infoWindows.  What is the easiest way to disable a function or active listener after the other button has been clicked?

Comment: The answer to your previous [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096807/how-to-disable-javascript-function-after-being-ran-once) does this work right?

Comment: wow, I had already forgot about this, it does work.  Thanks! It was a late night!

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case:

```
 addListenerOnce(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:Function)
```

would work

More on:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event